# How to display big string in ListView's items?

Tags: android, listview, multiline

I am getting my data from fire-base into a list view but the string i'm getting are rather long and the listView in android doesn't seem to support multiLine.
This is how my database looks like: [image: DB Pic]
The layoutFile is:

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".usersMessage">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

That's how I am getting my data in .java file

```
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AdminMessages");
    mListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,list);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);



    myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String value=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            list.add(value);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

That's how the data is being displayed in the listView:

[image]

Comment: if you want to show complete text of string then you need to remove that `singleLine = true` attribute, :)

Comment: I have removed it, it is still not working.

Comment: can you paste your item.xml code here ? :)

Comment: there is no item.xml

Comment: there is `android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line` it's android's default layout you can use your own too :)

Comment: hey umair can you please tell me where can i find this file in android studio project? I am sorry, I am kind of new to this thing

Comment: please check my answer and tell me if it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an `.xml` file in your `layouts folder`. Suppose that file name is abc.xml and it has a layout something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Edittext xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@android:id/text1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@color/white_color"
          android:drawablePadding="10dp"
          android:gravity="start"
          android:paddingLeft="5dp"
          android:paddingRight="5dp"
          android:paddingTop="2.5dp"
          android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
          android:textColor="@color/black_color"
          android:textStyle="normal"/>
```

now in your code replace `android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line` with `abc.xml`

Replace these lines with :

```
adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,list);
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

this:

```
  adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.abc,list);
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Happy to help... Good day :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these two lines to `TextView` in the `item.xml`

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Comment: OP wants to remove the `...`

Comment: hey, I can't find the item.xml in my android studio project structure. Can you tell me where can I find it?

Comment: I guess, I am late for answering :)